# Return_value_policy for method with void return type and optional parameter

Tags: boost-python

I have class with void method and optional argument looking like this:

```
class A
{
public:
    void method(int par1, bool par2 = false) { ... }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MEMBER_FUNCTION_OVERLOADS(method, A::method, 1, 2)
class_<A>("A")
  .def("method", &A::method, return_value_policy<reference_existing_object>(),method())
;
```

What is correct return_value_policy in this case? I've tried to avoid return policy completely however I've received following compile error then.

```
'boost::mpl::vector17<RT,most_derived<Target,ClassT>::type&,T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14> boost::python::detail::get_signature(RT (__cdecl ClassT::* )(T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14) volatile const,Target *)' : expects 2 arguments - 1 provided
```

Any suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've scrambled few things together. Bur I realized I do not need to use BOOST_PYTHON_MEMBER_FUNCTION_OVERLOADS but rather named arguments something like:

```
def("method", &A::method, (arg("par1"), arg("par2") = false))
```

Comment: The trick with the `arg(...)` expressions is really neat, thanks! The Boost.Python reference manual mentions that the argument to the `=` operator must be convertible to Python, so `false`, integers, floats should work without any problems.